Celery Dynamic Task Names
I am using Celery as part of my scraping tool that ends up generating a task for every endpoint it needs to pull from. When looking at logs or flower/celery-insights its difficult to understand what endpoint is being processed by that task. To my knowledge my options are to A) set the task name, B) set the task ID, or C) use metadata or D) a combination of A,B, or C.
I have been struggling with attempting to generate tasks with unique names based on a generator/iteration.
To keep things simple let's say I have the following:
import logging
from time import sleep

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://default:redis@redis:6379/0'
celery_app = Celery('celery_test', broker=CELERY_BROKER_URL, result_backend=CELERY_BROKER_URL)   

@celery_app.task(bind=True)
def print_num(num):
    logger.info(f"Processing number: {num}")
    # Simulate some processing
    sleep(20)
    logger.info(f"Number processed: {num}")

category_tasks = group(print_num.s(num) for num in range(10))
result = category_tasks.async_apply()

This would generate 10 tasks, all named celery_test.process_item with a different UUID for the task name. What I am trying to accomplish is to have the task names be releative to the number they are processing. ie celery_test.proces_item.1, celery_test.proces_item.2 ... celery_test.proces_item.10
How could this be accomplished?

Flower shows you the args and kwargs that the task was called with, so in your example num should be visible in the args column when looking at Flower's Tasks tab.

Ive been using Celery Insights, and yes I can see the args passed. This does not dynamically affect the task name though. Having thousands of tasks named the same is what I'm trying to address.

Oh okay, I wasn't familiar with Insights so I didn't understand why the arg wasn't enough. I see now.

I think dynamic task naming would be very difficult to get working, because in most cases the process that creates a Celery task is different from the process that consumes and executes the task. They rely on the name of the task being the same in both processes, so if you're trying to create tasks with dynamic names, both the publishing and consuming processes would need to have knowledge of the dynamic names. It would be hard for them to coordinate
